# update Views in layout when a view changes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-view

I have a LinearLayout with 2 views. when I move the upper view at runtime the second view doesn't move accordingly and I can't seem to find a solution. can anyone help?

here's the layout I'm using right now:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="test.itayrabin.toolbar2.TestActivity" android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="101dp"
    android:onClick="translate"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/lipsum"
    android:onClick="back"/>
```

It's just a LinearLayout with a button and a textView. I have the button's onClick set to a method that lowers it and the textView's onClick is just a method that brings everything back to it's original state.

here's the translate method:

```
public void translate(View view) {
    translationY +=10;
    button.setTranslationY(translationY);
}
```

I have tried making the root layout a Relative one, that didn't help.

I tried setting the padding of the textView

I tried setting the textView's top to the Button's bottom.

none of those worked.
Does anyone have an idea how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ViewProperties like translationX/Y/, rotationX/Y does not affect the layout of the view hierarchy.

If you want both view to be translated, you have to translate the second view as well.

Or you could add some margin on top of the first view, this will push both view downward.

Comment: And if I have a layout within a layout and one of the views inside the inner layout changes it's size, how can I update the inner layout's size? @pdegand59

Comment: With a requestLayout on the parent layout